# Visualizing the Commutative Property Beyond Three Numbers

Tags: visualization

I've been pondering how to intuitively visualize the commutative property of multiplication when dealing with more than three numbers. For two numbers, we can easily conceptualize this with the area of a rectangle, and for three, the volume of a cube serves as a great illustration. However, when we move to four or more numbers, the challenge becomes apparent due to our spatial limitations in representing higher dimensions.

Using tree diagrams, we can abstractly represent the multiplication of several numbers, but juxtaposing different trees doesn't quite capture the intuitive essence of the commutative property in the same way that geometric shapes do in lower dimensions.

Does anyone have insights or creative methods for visualizing this property for four or more numbers?

Comment: You may be interested in the [permutohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron).

Answer (score 1):

Commutative property is defined on two operands. For an expression involving more than two operands, usually we commutate the operands two at a time to derive a new order. An analogy would be tracking two dimensions at a time of a higher-dimensional orthogonal volume, knowing that at every step, they are commutative and no product is changed.